# What defines acoustic permeability of a material?

Tags: acoustics, material-science

I am developing a product in a startup which is a medical product basically measures air flow with ultrasonic sensors.

Since this is a medical product we need to protect our sensors from contamination, therefore, we need to separate the sensors from flowing air.

We tried Mesh filters that don't block sound but don't protect well from bacteria. And I am guessing maybe some thin flexible rubber or silicone might work, but I am not sure.

My question is:

- is there a material that can allow sound waves to pass through?
- Also, How can I search for it?

Because I am not good with terminology and I don't know where to look, How to look.

1. If you know a material that you think might work can you point it out?
2. If you are not sure about the materials can you give me keywords that I can search with?

Comment: If you question would be closed here, re-ask your question on https://engineering.stackexchange.com .